# How to display particular key value array first in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of values which was merged by two array . The given arrays are ordered by some query. Now i the new merged array having in order array values.

Now I want to order that array values by key 'desc' key  named 'featured' it contains numeric values

Example

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        ( 
          featured=> 0,
         shop_update =>a,b,c )
   [1] => stdClass Object
        ( 
          featured=> 1,
         shop_update =>a,,c ),
   [2] => stdClass Object
        ( 
          featured=> 1,
         shop_update =>a,c ),
```

How to order this array by featured desc ?

Any help?

Comment: You can use `Array sorting` here is a link http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 0):

usort must help:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->featured == $b->featured) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->featured < $b->featured) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: What is the argument ($a,$b) ?

Comment: @Aaru They are 2 array elements, compared: http://php.net/usort